# Output of date in dd/mm/yy format using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I would like to convert data from a format that contains the months of the year stored like Jan,Feb,Mar... etc to a more standard format dd/mm/yy.

I'm thinking of storing the text associated with the months in a hash. The result should be something like this.

```
INPUT                       OUTPUT
"DATE,04-Sep-2014"    ->   "04/09/14"
```

Comment: Use a [date module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho#Task::Kensho::Dates:-Date-Modules) or two.

Answer (score 4):

[Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) is a core module since v5.9.5:

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime
    ->strptime('DATE,04-Sep-2014', 'DATE,%d-%b-%Y')
    ->strftime('%d/%m/%y');
```

**output**

```
04/09/14
```

Comment: Thanks choroba, but I this is not a solution for me, as I don't have Time::Piece and I can't install it either (not possible for me, as the script needs to run over multiple machines).

Comment: As choroba said, it's been a core module since 2007. You really don't want to be using a version of Perl that's older than that.

Comment: If you can install your script, you can install a module. They are two different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need without recourse to any nasty modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print transform_date('DATE,04-Sep-2014');

{
   my (%months, $months_re);

   sub transform_date {

      my ($date_str) = @_;

      unless ($months_re) {
         @months{qw/ Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec /} = 1 .. 12;
         $months_re = join '|', keys %months;
         $months_re = qr/(?:$months_re)/;
      }

      return unless my ($d, $m, $y) = $date_str =~ /(\d\d)-($months_re)-(\d\d\d\d)/;
      sprintf '%02d/%02d/%02d', $d, $months{$m}, $y % 100;
   }
}
```

**output**

```
04/09/14
```

Comment: @jaypal: Yes, I like `Time::Piece` a lot. I was making fun of the OP's comment *"this is not a solution for me, as I don't have Time::Piece and I can't install it either"*. So many people don't understand that installing most modules is just a matter of copying a `pm` file.